# Computational singularity error when running partial mantel test in R

Tags: cochran-mantel-haenszel

I've been running a series of partial mantel tests in R using the 'ecodist' package. Each test represents a different distance hypothesis relating genetic distance to cost distance to travel through an environment between sampling points, while partialling out an alternative cost distance hypothesis:

c1.c2 <- mantel(genetic_distance ~ cost_distance1 + cost_distance2)

This runs perfectly until I reach hypotheses representing high cost distances (with associated high number values composing the input matrices).  Here R generates the following error:

"Error in solve.default(tomat %*% omat) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.14306e-16"

Most of the Q&A associated with this error are related to GLM or other regression type analyses, and suggestions have to do with removing strongly correlated, linearly dependent variables. However, this doesn't seem to apply to this case. I ran the same partial mantels that threw errors in R in a different program (zt: http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v007i10), and they ran just fine. Perhaps this is just an issue of R not being able to handle very large numbers? Any suggestions are appreciated. And if it is simply a computational issue handling very large numbers, I wanted to share this workaround for others that run into this problem.